# Combine `Protocol` with base class requirement, type intersection

Tags: python, typing

I want to express some type which inherits from `nn.Module`. I would do so as follows:

```py
ModuleType = TypeVar("ModuleType", bound=nn.Module)
```

At the same time, I want to express that it has an `__init__` function of a certain format. I would do so using `Protocol`, as follows:

```py
class InitWithCfgProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, cfg: dict):
        ...
```

Now, how can I express a type which has both properties? Basically an intersection of `ModuleType` and `InitWithCfgProtocol`. Is this possible?

Further, how can this again be expressed as a `TypeVar`, such that I can use it as a template argument for a `Generic`? Like this:

```py
ModuleInitWithCfgType = TypeVar(...)  # ?


@dataclass
class ModuleFactory(Generic[ModuleInitWithCfgType]):
    module_class: Type[ModuleInitWithCfgType]

    def make(self, cfg: dict) -> ModuleInitWithCfgType:
        return self.module_class(cfg)
```

In this example, I want to have proper checks (via PyCharm, mypy or similar) for:

- `self.module_class(cfg)` - it should warn when I pass wrong arguments
- `factory = ModuleFactory(MyModule)` - it should warn when I pass a wrong `MyModule` class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but judging by the [PEP for the protocols](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/), I don't think there's a way to express that. The rationale for protocols was to express structural typing only, minimizing the intersection with abstract base classes and other means of expressing type constraints. (Specifically, the idea of [protocols subclassing normal classes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#protocols-subclassing-normal-classes) has been reviewed and rejected)

I'd say your best bet is to introduce an abstract base class with a custom subclasscheck:

```py
class ModuleType(ABC):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, sub_cls):
        if cls is not ModuleType:
            return NotImplemented
        return isinstance(sub_cls, nn.Module) and isinstance(sub_cls, InitWithCfgProtocol)
```

(This implies `@runtime_checkable` for InitWithCfgProtocol, and results in `isinstance` and `issubclass` working properly for `ModuleType`. I can't vouch that a static type checker would be able to recognize it)